# Cannot find module './product-list/product-list.component'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

I'm just starting in angular and I'm trying to add a top-bar component I've followed the flow of the [app directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7722.png)

but it still seems to be giving me issues  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLgxQ.png)

I have imported my components and added them to my [declarations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arV9s.png)

This is just a proof of concept to figure out how the angular workflow, I can't seem to get passed importing...I've recreated this three times and used the cli..no luck...any advice is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the relevant code in textual form rather in as an image. Supplementary images can be helpful but are not sufficient.

Comment: Hey buddy, please check your file names. Product list file name do not match with your path. Your product file end with "componet.html" and your path spelling is "component". There is difference of "n" in both.
So i think you should rename your product file by:
1) Product-list.component.css
2) Product-list.component.html
3) Product-list.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to match the import with the folder name which is `Product-list` and not `product-list`